# $X_i = \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_i^2)$, with $\sigma_1^2 \geq \sigma_2^2 \geq \dots \geq 0$ and $\sum_i \sigma^2_i = 1$

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{X_k\}$ be independent random variables such that $X_i = \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma_i^2)$, with $\{\sigma_i^2\}$ such that $\sigma_1^2 \geq \sigma_2^2 \geq \dots \geq 0$ and $\sum_i \sigma^2_i = 1$.

What is the limit of $\{S_n\}$ in $L^2(\Omega. \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$? Before, show that $S_n$ converges in distribution.

My attempt:

I guess that $S_n$ converges to $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, because $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \sigma_i^2 = 1$.

I demonstrated that $\{S_n\}$ is Cauchy in $L^2$:

Given $\epsilon > 0$, as $\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty} \sigma_i^2 = 1$ and $\sigma_1^2 \geq \sigma_2^2 \geq \dots$, there is $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{i=N}^{+\infty} \sigma_i^2 < \epsilon$.

\medskip

Then, for $m \geq n \geq N$ we have that:

\begin{align*}
    E[|S_m - S_n|^2] &= E[|\sum_{i=n+1}^{m} X_i|^2] \\
    &= Var[\sum_{i=n+1}^m X_i] \\
    &= \sum_{i=n+1}^m Var[X_i] \\
    &= \sum_{i= n+1}^m \sigma_i^2 \\
    &\leq \sum_{i = n+1}^{+\infty} \sigma_i^2\\
    &< \epsilon
\end{align*}

Comment: What is $S_n$?  The sum of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I forgot to write!

Comment: Do you mean you want convergence in distribution? Then characteristic functions are a quick way. Alternatively, slutsky's theorem.

Answer (score 0):

> **Lemma 1 (Levy's Equivalence Theorem)：** Let $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n,\cdots$  be independent random variables and $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}{X_i}$. Then 
>   $$S_n\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}S\Leftrightarrow S_n\overset{\mathbb{P}}{\rightarrow}S\Leftrightarrow S_n\overset{d}{\rightarrow}S \ .$$
>
> **Lemma 2 ：** Let $\left( \Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu \right)$ be a finite measure space and $1\leq p<\infty$. Suppose $f$ and $\left\{ f_n \right\}$ are functions in $L^p\left( \Omega \right)$ and  $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost everywhere or in measure. Then 
>   $$f_n\overset{L^p}{\rightarrow}f \Leftrightarrow \left\| f_n \right\|_p \rightarrow \left\| f \right\|_p \ .$$

Now we can easily show that $S_n$ converges to a $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ random  variable $S$ in distribution by using characteristic function. Then by lemma 1, we have that $S_n\overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow}S$.

By lemma 2, if we want to prove that $S_n\overset{L^2}{\rightarrow}S$, we only need to prove that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\mathbb{E}\left( S_n^2 \right)}=\mathbb{E}\left( S^2 \right)=1\ .$$
Obviously, it is trivial.